# Jasmine fit steps are not executing in order

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have function which return me application status

```
getDecision: function() {

    browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(decisionPage), 60000); // verify the decision and proceed further depending upon it.
    element(by.xpath(rejectImage)).isPresent().then(function(result) {
        if (result) {

            console.log('Application is rejected');
            finalResult = 'Rejected';

        } else {

            element(by.xpath(queueImage)).isPresent().then(function(result1) {

                if (result1) {

                    console.log('Application is sent to underwriter for review');
                    finalResult = 'Queue';
                } else {

                    console.log('Application is approved');
                    finalResult = 'Approved';
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Then in same class I am returning the finalResult as :

```
returnDecision: function() {

    console.log('Result is::' + finalResult);
    return finalResult;
},
```

And then in admin portal again I need to take decision based upon status from above function as:

```
takeDecision: function(testData) {

    // Verifying if the case is queued or rejected
    if (decision.returnDecision() === 'Queue') {

        // Approving the case
        if (testData.croDecision.apprvDecision === "Approve") {

            // basePage.clickElement(approveButton);
            utils.sleep(2);
            var approveButton = browser.driver.findElement(By.css(croApproveButton));
            approveButton.click();


        } else {

            var declineButton = browser.driver.findElement(By.css(croDeclineButton));
            declineButton.click();
            utils.sleep(2);
            browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath(remarkDecline)).sendKeys('for testing purpose');
        }
        utils.sleep(2);
        browser.driver.findElement(By.linkText("Submit")).click();
        utils.sleep(2);
        expect(browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath(decisionSuccessMessage)).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

    } else /*if (decision.returnDecision() === 'Rejected')*/ {

        console.log("Case is rejected, no further action");
    }
},
```

and in spec file I am calling this method after I punch a case using user as follow:

```
fdescribe('Data Entry For Applicant(HL1)', function() {

            beforeAll(function() {

                this.actionwords = Object.create(require('../actionwords.js').Actionwords);
            });

            afterAll(function() {

                testData.login.username = 'softcellqa1@gmail.com';

                //logout of the app
                loginPage.logout(testData)
            });


            fit('test', function() {

                testData.loan.existingloan = 'No';
                this.actionwords.housingLoanWithoutCoApplicant(testData);
                this.actionwords.takeDecision(testData);
            });
});
```

this.actionwords.takeDecision(testData) is always executed before this.actionwords.housingLoanWithoutCoApplicant

Please let me know what is wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Make sure, `housingLoanWithoutCoApplicant` returns a promise.

Comment: Thanks, This is working!